# Gini Feature Importance for XGBoost Classification Not making sense

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-selection, boosting, importance

I am trying to look at the feature importance in my model. The most important feature according to the gini importance in my xgboost is %97 zero in my dataset. Meaning that 97% of all values in the column are 0, and it is the most important feature according to the model.

Also, when I plot the SHAP values, that feature is ranked at the last place.

How come that feature is the most important feature for my model? I would think that it would not be important for a model. Can anyone tell me why that might be?

Edit: This is a multiclass classification model with 3 target classes.
This feature takes values from 0 to 150, so it is not binary. It just so happens that 97% of the rows are equal to 0, the rest of the 3% of rows ranging from 1.45232 to 150.522 etc.

There are 70 features in my model.

Class 0 has 75% prevalence

Class 1 has 12% prevalence

Class 2 has 13% prevalence.

Features are mostly highly correlated within groups, because it has mean,median, std, max, min values for 3 feature groups.

Comment: 1. Is the value "1" highly predictive of the target class?  2. Other than answering that question - which may also answer your question - you'd need to tell us considerably more about your model - how many features, frequencies of the target class, etc. for people to get started on answering it.

Comment: @jbowman I updated the question with the answers to your comment.

Comment: Following point 1 of @jbowman, I think it would be helpful to look at a side by side comparison of the class distribution of those with that 97% feature = 0 vs when it's nonzero. Is one of these combinations empty?

Comment: Note that in tree-based models, the actual values of the features don't matter, only their rank order (within the feature, of course.)  It may be that some subset of the 3% is highly predictive of, say, class 1 and another subset of class 2.